# Как развернуть сервер Nodejs Express на Https

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, socket.io, express

Есть сервер Node.js + Express

```html
var app = require('express')();

var fs = require('fs');


var options = {

        key: fs.readFileSync('private.key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt.pem')

    };

var https = require('https').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(https);

https.listen(3000, function()
{

    console.log('Server started on port 3000');

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

 console.log('Connected....');
});
```

При подключении по Https выдает ошибку:  SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP (Это Firefox)
Вроде и указал сертификаты в формате .pem
И все равно не работает
Сервер Apache
Подключаюсь по домену через 3000 порт

Comment: Я надеюсь, вы это делаете только для тестов. Не нужно в продакшене оффлод ssl делать на стороне ноды, прошу вас.

Comment: Тоесть не желательно использовать ноду в качестве сервера? Можно по подробнее? И как лучше это реализовать правильно? Я просто пару дней как начал изучать ноду.

Comment: Ноду можно, но оффлод ssl нужно делать на стороне nginx, а в ноду проксировать уже расшифрованные данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был не внимателен. Не передал опции в .Server(app);
Было .Server(app);
Нужно .createServer(options, app)

И еще, может кому поможет. Обязательно конвертируйте свои ключи в .pem формат